# Proof of commutative property in Boolean algebra a∨b = b∨a, a∧b = b∧a,

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, binary

Does anybody know how to prove commutative property in Boolean algebra?

$a \vee b= b \vee a$
$a \wedge b = b \wedge a$

Thank you, have a nice day.

Edit:

Algebra $(A,\wedge,\vee,',0,1)$

$\vee, \wedge$ are binary operations, $'$ is unary operation, $0,1$ are constants

- Associativity of binary operations: $(a \wedge b) \wedge c = a \wedge (b \wedge c)$, $(a \vee b) \vee c = a \vee (b \vee c)$
- Distributivity: $a\wedge(b\vee c) = (a\wedge b)\vee(a\wedge c)$, $(b\vee c)\wedge a = (b\vee a)\wedge (c \vee a)$
- $'$: $(a')\wedge a = a\wedge(a') = 0$, $(a')\vee a = a\vee (a') = 1$
- $0$: $a\wedge 0 = 0\wedge a = 0$, $0\vee a = a\vee 0 = a$
- $1$: $a\wedge 1 = 1\wedge a = a$, $1\vee a = a\vee 1 = 1$

Comment: Use the definitions of $\vee$ and $\wedge$.  What have you even tried?

Comment: Use a truth table to compare $a\lor b$ vs. $b\lor a$... and do the same for $a\land b$... use truth tables to prove the equalities.

Comment: To get the taste, e.g. *idempotency* is implied, as follows:
$$a=a\lor 0=a\lor(a\land a')=(a\lor a)\land (a\lor a')=(a\lor a)\land 1=a\lor a$$

Comment: We also get uniqueness of complements, in that $x\land y=0,\ y\lor x=1\ \implies y=x'$  (and its dual $y\land x=0,\ x\lor y=1\ \implies y=x'$ ). I think it can get it closer

Comment: Given that it is a *boolean* algebra, there are only two elements: $0$ and $1$. As such, there are only four pairs of values that any $a$ and the $b$ can take on, and the commutative identities for all these pairs are easily verified by the basic laws involving $0$ and $1$: no need to use Association, Distribution, or complement.

Comment: @Bram28 I think that the question is not well posed and that what the it should read is: given an algebra as defined after the edit, prove it is a boolean algebra. So it is not taken beforehand to be a boolean algebra. At least that's the only sense I can make of this. And if that's the intention, I think it is a very nice question, even if not very deep.

Comment: @amrsa If that would make for a nice question, then that's probably it. ... with my interpretation it's clearly not an interesting question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we prove idempotency ($a=a\lor a$), though we might not need it later on.
$$a=a\lor 0=a\lor(a\land a')=(a\lor a)\land (a\lor a')=(a\lor a)\land 1=a\lor a$$
Second, we prove uniqueness of the complement, in the sense that 
$a\land b=0,\ b\lor a=1\implies b=a'$:
$$a'=a'\land 1=a'\land (b\lor a)=(a'\land b)\lor (a'\land a)=a'\land b\\
b=1\land b=(a\lor a')\land b= (a\land b)\lor (a'\land b)=a'\land b $$
In particular, it implies $a''=a$.

Then certain forms of absorbance follows: $a=a\lor(b\land a)$ 
$$a'\lor (a\lor(b\land a))=1\\
(a\lor(b\land a))\land a'=(a\land a')\lor(b\land a\land a')=0 $$
We similarly get $a=(a\land b)\lor a$, and two other equations by duality.

Then, we get a key lemma: $a\lor b=1 \implies a'=a'\land b \implies b\lor a=1$: 
Supposed $a\lor b=1$, we get $a'=a'\land 1=a'\land(a\lor b)=(a'\land a)\lor (a'\land b)=a'\land b$. 
Supposed $a'=a'\land b$, we get $b\lor a'=b\lor (a'\land b)=b$ by absorbance, so $\ b\lor a=(b\lor a')\lor a=1$.

Note that this implies $a\lor x\lor a'=1$ for any $x$, as we have $\ (x\lor a')\lor a=1$. 
Using their dual statements as well ($a\land b=0\iff b\land a=0$ and $a'\land x\land a=0$), we can finally arrive to commutativity by observing that both $a\lor b$ and $b\lor a$ are complements of $a'\land b'$:
$$(a\lor b)\lor (a'\land b')=(a\lor b\lor a')\land (a\lor b\lor b')=1\\
(b\lor a)\lor (a'\land b')=(b\lor a\lor a')\land (b\lor a\lor b')=1\\
-\cdot-\cdot- \\
(a'\land b')\land (a\lor b)=(a'\land b'\land a)\lor(a'\land b'\land b)=0\\
(a'\land b')\land (b\lor a)=(a'\land b'\land b)\lor(a'\land b'\land a)=0
$$

Comment: Your proof of join-idempotency uses a form of distributivity that is not part of the axioms. Of course that one will follow from the ones we have and the absorption laws, which could be proven first. On the other hand, if I didn't miss anything, you didn't really use any idempotency law.